# Boostrapping from Exponential Sample to estimate the quantiles

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap, monte-carlo, quantiles

I have the problem where I want to estimate the quantiles of a distribution by bootstrapping. Fortunately I do know the original DGP which I chose to be an Exp(1/4) distribution and so the theoretical distributions can be determined.

However, I want to implement an estimator for the 25th, 50th and 75th quantiles and using bootstrap show that they provide an approximation to these true quantiles.

I also want to do this with an initial sample size of 6 and then another time with an initial sample size of 100. I have implemented this in R and have the following.

[image]

However, I wanted to try Bootstrap Monte Carlo for a sample size of 10000 but my quantiles seem way off. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

My general process is:
For the n=6 sample,

1. Generate initial sample from DGP of size 6
2. Resample from this n^n times (exact bootstrap distribution) and then on each resample calculate the sample quantiles at the 25th, 50th and 75th level.
3. Calculate the mean, variance, bias and MSE across these sample quantiles to get properties of the estimator (sample quantiles)

My general process is:
For the n=100 sample,

1. Generate initial sample from DGP of size 100
2. Resample from this 100 times with replacement of size 100 and then on each resample calculate the sample quantiles at the 25th, 50th and 75th level.
3. Calculate the mean, variance, bias and MSE across these sample quantiles to get properties of the estimator (sample quantiles)

For the Monte Carlo simulation of size 10,000 I am implementing the same procdure as for the n=100 initial sample size. But I am getting bootstrap means nowhere near the theoretical quantiles.

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding that the bootstrap will approximate the sample quantiles and not the exact quantiles of the original distribution as the initial samples may not even capture the true quantiles of Exp(1/4)

Comment: When you say:

Resample from this 100 times with replacement of size 100

Are you saying you're only doing 100 replications? Try increasing that to 2,000. 100 is a bit low. I'm not sure I follow whu you need 10k simulation outer loop, seems high?

Comment: Your comment that bootstrapping will in a sense be centred on the initial sample, rather than the original distribution, is one of the many things going on here.  I suspect another is that the expected value of the initial sample $0.25$ quantile may be higher than the population $0.25$ quantile (the $-4\log_e(1-1/4) \approx 1.15073$ as shown in your tables).

Comment: @Henry I think your point is correct, I have noticed that the means of these quantiles after bootstrapping are closer to the initial sample quantiles. Is it possible that they would ever converge to the Exp(1/4) true 25th 50th and 75th quantiles?

Comment: The means of the bootstrap quantiles will converge to some values, but what those values are will depend on the initial sample (your initial comment), so are unlikely to be the population quantiles.  What I do not know is whether they are is likely to be closer than the initial sample quantiles were.